# How to index an object wrapping a (nested 2D) numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, indexing

I have a program where I want to get use of numpy to get most efficiency using pure Python. There are two classes:

```
import numpy as np

class Individual:
    def __init__(self, vector: np.ndarray) -> None:
        self.value = vector
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.value[index]

class Population:
    def __init__(self, individuals=np.array([])):
        self.individuals = individuals

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.individuals[index]

ind1 = Individual(np.array([1, 2]))
ind2 = Individual(np.array([3, 4]))
population = Population(np.array([ind1, ind2]))
```

`Population` is a container for individuals. So population looks like this `np.array[individual1, individual2, individual3, ...]`.

What I want is to use masks for slicing to omit loops in my program. For example, use such an array:

```
mask =  [[True, False], [False, True]]
```

as a mask on the `population` object itself:

```
population[mask] = blblblbllb...
```

But my problem is that I cannot use 2D slicing while my population consists of `Individual` objects. Is there any solution to make it work in quite nice way and stay with this classes?

My aim is to have funcionality that let me do:

```
population[mask] = population2[mask]
```

while still `type(population[0])` is `Individual` not `np.ndarray`

I tried to make `Individual` like custom array containers described in [the numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html) and make use of `def __array__`, but the problem was that if I make a population like this

```
pop = Population(np.array([Individual(some_array)]))
```

when I try to index, `pop[0]` is no longer an `Individual` object, is just a `np.ndarray`.

Comment: What's `population.individuals.shape`?  (`population.shape` doesn't work).  I think it's 1d.  `individuals` is an 1d object dtype array of `Individual` instances.  `population[[2,1]`  will return a new object dtype array, not a `Population` instance.  You'll need to a lot more code to make your classes 'array-like'.  For a beginner I'm not sure that's worth the effort.  OOP style coding is of limited use when working with numpy arrays.

Comment: It's not all the code for the classes. It's just a part that have real influence on what mu problem is. Of course it is worth since i want to still improve my skills so if u had any ideas or docs that could help me just post them. Also do not understand this phrase 'population[[2,1] will return a new object dtype array, not a Population instance', I guess u miss here something.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the page you linked](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html), one can implement the `__array__` method to indicate to `numpy` functions how to convert the object to a numpy array. But trying to index the object will still just call its `__getitem__` method. So we can combine both to get:

```py
class Population:
    def __init__(self, individuals=np.array([])):
        self.individuals = individuals

    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        return np.array([ind.value for ind in self.individuals])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return np.asarray(self).__getitem__(index)
```

And now this will work:

```py
mask = [[True, False], [False, True]]
print(population[mask])
```

and will give:

```
[1 4]
```

as expected.

Comment: Ok, but still probably didn't get the main problem here. The clue is that of course mask is working well with what you wrote but if u try to get population[0], what u get is np.array class object not Individual anymore. What makes me unable to later calls some methods on this object like population[0].some_indiv_method()